# Image of unit sphere being hyper ellipse proof (SVD)

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, svd

When I check for the proof of singular value decomposition, they all assume the following is true:

> The image of the unit sphere under any $m * n$ matrix is a hyper
>   ellipse.

However I could not find a decent proof for this, even though I googled for hours. I keep seeing notes like: "This geometric fact is not obvious. We shall restate it in the language of linear algebra and prove it later. For the moment, assume it is true."

Maybe I am using wrong keywords. Could you please give me a link, text book name, etc. (a reference) for this proof?

Comment: I haven't seen proofs that assume this. For example, Trefethen's proof doesn't assume it. Rather, this geometric result is usually given as a consequence of the SVD (in my experience).

Comment: @littleO should not it have a standalone proof as well? Also are we talking about this proof?: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs322/2008sp/stuff/TrefethenBau_Lec4_SVD.pdf

Comment: I think you're quoting from Trefethen. But he is simply saying that the proof of the SVD will be given later (and it is given later).  At this point he is simply *motivating* the SVD and providing some intuition, but not proving it yet.

Comment: Yes, that's the passage I was thinking of.  It's from his book Numerical Linear Algebra, which contains a rigorous proof of the SVD.

Comment: @littleO it was a pretty good proof, thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $T$ is a linear map on a finite-dimensional inner product space $V$. The Polar Decomposition states that there is an isometry $S$ on $V$ such that
$$
T = S \sqrt{T^* T}.
$$
Because $\sqrt{T^*T}$ is a positive operator, the Finite-Dimensional Spectral Theorem states that there is an orthonormal basis $e_1, \dots, e_n$ of $V$ and nonnegative numbers $s_1, \dots, s_n$ such that
$$
\sqrt{T^*T}e_j = s_j e_j
$$
for $j = 1, \dots n$. Thus $\sqrt{T^*T}$ maps the unit sphere of $V$ to a hyper-ellipse, and because $S$ is an isometry, $T$ also maps the unit sphere of $V$ to a hyper-ellipse.

The Singular Value Decomposition follows easily from the Polar Decomposition without mentioning hyper-ellipses (see, for example, Chapter 7 in my book *Linear Algebra Done Right*).

Comment: Did somebody really downvote this answer? It's a great answer and we're lucky to have Axler himself posting here.